# Cannot read property 'substring' of null

Tags: javascript

I am unable to resolve an issue with my code. I am trying to run the [code](https://codepen.io/codearts/pen/ZyzNBw) but it gives me an error. It seems my code don't know what is `contentDivs`

```
for (a = 0; a < links.length; a++) {
  // number of links should match number of content
  links[a].style.backgroundColor = 'magenta';
  contentDivs[a].style.display = 'none';
}
```

where
var contentDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('content'); 
and i tried doing `console.log(contentDivs.innerHTML);` and `console.log(contentDivs.textContent);` but it comes out as undefined.

What am i missing?

> Cannot read property 'substring' of null

Code below:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('link'), // add a class to the links and get them all
  contentDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('content'); // same with the content blocks

for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { // loop through the links to add the event listeners
  var link = links[i];

  // add event listener
  link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    // reset color and hide content:
    for (a = 0; a < links.length; a++) {
      // number of links should match number of content
      links[a].style.backgroundColor = 'magenta';
      contentDivs[a].style.display = 'none';
    }

    // set colour of clicked
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';

    // show clicked content
    document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute("href").substring(1)).style.display = 'block';
  })
}
```

```css
ul {
  wudth: 100%;
  clear: both
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  background: magenta;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* add this so only home is showing when page loads */

.content:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home" class="link">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" class="link">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#articles" class="link">Articles</a></li>
  <li><a href="#connect" class="link">Connect</a></li>
</ul>

<div>
  <div id="home" class="content">
    home
    <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque erat velit, placerat sit amet nisl sed, aliquet bibendum nunc. Donec varius dui sed velit volutpat, et rutrum turpis fini
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="contact" class="content">
    contact
    <br> . Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum aliquam iaculis turpis et efficitur. Integer sollicitudin tincidunt imperdiet. Nam pharetra orci ac viverra dapibus. Ut feugiat nisi sit
    amet hendrerit scelerisque. Nulla scelerisque mauris metus, eu facilisis lectus euismod vel. Pellentesque magna mi, scelerisque vel rutrum quis, volutpat et diam.
  </div>
  <div id="articles" class="content">
    articles
    <br> . Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum aliquam iaculis turpis et efficitur. Integer sollicitudin tincidunt imperdiet. Nam pharetra orci ac viverra dapibus. Ut feugiat nisi sit
    amet hendrerit scelerisque. Nulla scelerisque mauris metus, eu facilisis lectus euismod vel. Pellentesque magna mi, scelerisque vel rutrum quis, volutpat et diam.
  </div>
  <div id="connect" class="content">
    connect
    <br> . Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum aliquam iaculis turpis et efficitur. Integer sollicitudin tincidunt imperdiet. Nam pharetra orci ac viverra dapibus. Ut feugiat nisi sit
    amet hendrerit scelerisque. Nulla scelerisque mauris metus, eu facilisis lectus euismod vel. Pellentesque magna mi, scelerisque vel rutrum quis, volutpat et diam.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code in the question is completely unrelated to the problem... There's no `.substring()` call which could fail.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: @Andreas The code mentioned above is where the problem starts coming and follows till the end.

Comment: No it doesn't. There is no `.substring()` which could throw the mentioned error. Add the complete code in the question.

Comment: @Andreas I have linked a jsfiiddle.

Comment: I copied the html you posted above with the js in the fiddle and it works fine... the html you have in the fiddle originally breaks it.

Comment: The errors are because you've got 4 links and 2 content divs. Try adding 2 more content divs on your codepen example and you'll see it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[`document.getElementsByClassName('content');`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** returns an array.

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of
>   the given class names. When called on the document object, the
>   complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also
>   call getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will return only
>   elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the
>   given class names.

what you are doing here `console.log(contentDivs.innerHTML);` is acessing `innerHTML` property of array there is no such property in array thus returns undefined.

you have to do `console.log(contentDivs[0].innerHTML);`

Comment: TO knows that: `contentDivs[a]`; and this won't throw a _"Cannot read property 'substring' of null"_ error!

Comment: I think he's having problems inside his `for` loop, where he's accessing the array correctly.

Comment: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jc0ouvsb/) is a working example but I wonder what is wrong with above mentioned link

Comment: @Andreas Here he is logging incorrect `where var contentDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('content'); and i tried doing console.log(contentDivs.innerHTML); and console.log(contentDivs.textContent); but it comes out as undefined.`

Comment: @Andreas In the code i can't see any code accessing a `substring` property